# Error while posting the file to REST file api endpoint

Tags: php

I am trying to upload the order status file to update the status of orders.

Following is the request format:

```
POST /v1/orders/confirm/ HTTP/1.1
Host: file-api.fillz.com
X-FillZ-Access-Key: EXAMPLEACCESSKEY
X-FillZ-Date: 20141118T222611Z
X-FillZ-Signature: ced6826de95e2bfadd8f937f0ac708e8669e98d4c0145114c84f54174ace327b
Content-Type: application/tab-delimited
_content: 'order-id     status
       1000 shipped'
```

order.tab file contents:

```
order-id    status
79822165    packed
```

**PHP code:**

```
$filepath=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Fillz/order.tab';

$checksum = hash_file('sha256',$filepath);

$encoded_url = utf8_encode("https://file-api.fillz.com/v1/orders/confirm/");

echo "url: $encoded_url <br />";


$input_date = gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z', time()); // GMT/UTC format YYYYMMDDThhmmssZ

echo "Date: " . $input_date . "<br />";


$final_string = "POST\n$encoded_url\n$input_date\n$checksum";

echo "<pre>final string: $final_string</pre><br/>";

$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $final_string, $secret_key);

$target_url = 'https://file-api.fillz.com/v1/orders/confirm/';

$file_name_with_full_path = realpath('./order.tab');

echo $file_name_with_full_path;

$postfile = array('_contents' => '@' . $file_name_with_full_path);

$headers = array(
    'X-FillZ-Access-Key:'.$access_key,
    'X-FillZ-Date:'.$input_date,
    'X-FillZ-Signature:'.$signature,
    'Content-Type:application/tab-delimited'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
 echo $ch;
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

But I am getting error: "message": "Incorrect authentication credentials."
I have created proper signature and date and everything as expected. But still error is shown. Kindly help.

Comment: Hm, the code looks alright (assuming that the signature generation conforms to what the service demands). Maybe you should refer to fillz.com with a support request?

Comment: Hello, I somehow solved the problem. The problem was the file contents. As the data to be sent is expected in tab separated format. But, when I read the data from file, I did not get in the required format though the data is written in the file with appropriate tab separation and new line. So, I created the string from the file content with required /t and /n and passed as $postfield. And it worked. :)